# How can I read content from web using Java?

Tags: java, android, json, web

I never had this tough reading content from online with other language, I am developing an android app, It's need to read some JSON data from online. But I googled it and gave it a try on my own, but nothing is working as I expected

I want to read that JSON from the web, is there any good way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do a search on volley or ok http for android on google. (Though ok http is obsolete but volley is surely a good alternative)

Comment: Thanks found a video tutorial about volley, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) + [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) libraries. They can satisfy wide range of expectations and have perfect samples.